# Compiling Java or Swift Codes on Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, swift

Let say I have'nt a mac.I wrote some swift code on a txt file.It's a simple iPhone application that puts a button and label to view programatically.Is there a way to compile it on visual studio? Can i obtain the .app or .apk files.I heard about Xamarin.I wonder how Xamarin generates .app and .apk files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write native Android code in Java, you'll need to use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html). There's no way to compile Swift code on Windows, so you'll need a Mac for that (or you could try getting Mac OS X running on your Windows machine).

Xamarin code is written in C# and interacts with Xamarin's APIs that act as an adapter to the native iOS/Android code. This allows it to compile the same code individually to each platform so that it can run as a native app. You can't use Xamarin to write in native Swift or Java.

Comment: What does xamarin actually do when generating .app and .apk files.